Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: G
I am using the import-range function to pull data from 5 different workbooks into one master sheet.
I am working with a date drop down and need each query to only return the entries that match the date of the selected by the drop down in Cell B2
This is my formula:
 =query(IMPORTRANGE("147XavtJCnSy1mlTPHU9MgOhv2MoTx6YCUyzguxF5IBU", "SunCay Cruise Lines's entries!C:F"), "Select *
Where G= date """&text(B2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" ")

This is my error code:
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: G

I have also tried using Col 7 instead of G, however, the same error occurs.

What were you expecting G to be?  A column?  A variable?  Something else?


You may try:
=query(importrange("147XavtJCnSy1mlTPHU9MgOhv2MoTx6YCUyzguxF5IBU", "SunCay Cruise Lines's entries!C:G"), "Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 Where Col5= date '"&text(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")


Since you are importing an array of 5 columns (C:G), Column_C becomes Col1 & Column_D → Col2 ................... Column_G → Col5

OR
=let(Σ,importrange("147XavtJCnSy1mlTPHU9MgOhv2MoTx6YCUyzguxF5IBU", "SunCay Cruise Lines's entries!C:G"),
 filter(choosecols(Σ,1,2,3,4),choosecols(Σ,5)=B2))

